# Cost of hosting web-app grails/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grails, amazon-ec2, cloud, cloud-hosting

I have been trying to search around and have not really found an answer for the cost of a web app I want to host. Its not a small one, and the AWS calculator gives me crazy prices.

http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html?key=my-free-website

I am trying to host a rails/grails app (its grails, but I figure that it would cost about the same).

I did some calculations to expect how much data transfer, but I've never done this before, so I'm not sure about the certainty.

I will be hosting around 20,000 pdfs of about 1mb each. I'm expecting about 25,000 GB data out a year from loading pages and files. I'm expecting about 2,000 GB data-in per year. I think I need about 50 to 70 GB GB of storage for the files and database.

Around how much should I expect to pay? Its a grails application.

Thank you!

Daniel

PS: The similar questions I found deal with only smaller applications, and in those even people who are very experienced mentioned the AWS calculator as being hard to figure out.

Comment: Dreamhost single plan offers unlimited storage and transfer, plus Apache Passenger module for Rails. It's a usual PHP rate of $100/year.
They don't have MongoDB, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd also look at cloudfoundry (http://cloudfoundry.com), it's currently free while in beta, comes with a grails plugin that is really great as well as STS integration.

I believe you can also use it to deploy to aws their service is better later.

Answer (score 1):

S3 calc says that it will costs you about $9 per month for storing this data (looks no to expensive) and $300 for data transfer (are you sure that there will be few terabytes of data transfer a month?)

BTW, if your app is designed for storing PDF, it's main part of your app, then there will be no significant difference between using Grails or RoR

Comment: How exactly are you making those calculations? Thanks!